# IBM Clearcase plugin installation issue with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I am trying to install IBM Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.6.0.0 following instructions on [IBM site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674) on Eclipse Juno CDT.

I am using `Install New Software` > `Add` with the following URL.

http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/

Installation fails with the following message

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software currently installed: Rational ClearCase MVFS
>   Support 7.6.0.v201105111445
>   (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.feature.group
>   7.6.0.v201105111445) Missing requirement: Rational ClearCase Refresh Provider For MVFS Support 7.6.0.v201105111445
>   (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh 7.6.0.v201105111445) requires
>   'bundle org.eclipse.update.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Rational ClearCase MVFS Support
>   7.6.0.v201105111445 (com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh.feature.group
>   7.6.0.v201105111445) To: com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh [7.6.0.v201105111445]

My question is : is this an issue of the plugin which does not support Eclipse Platform 4.X ? Or is there something wrong with my installation ?

For the record, the installation of the same plugin works correctly with Eclipse Indigo CDT.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the hints from [Eclipse Help Site](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/porting/removals.html#updateManager).

It's not a real issue with the plugin, but rather with the removal of the old Eclipse Update Manager APIs from Juno. 
What I did was to download an older Update Manager jar, drop it in the plugins folder, and them try the installation again. Now it works.

(One possible location for the download - [Grepcode](http://repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.4.2/plugins/org.eclipse.update.core_3.2.202.R34x_v20081128.jar))

Comment: Just a small note for everyone who will come across this topic, as many do. This workaround works great when used on 32-bit version of Eclipse. Otherwise, with 64-bit you will get a nasty filter dependency error for IBM ClearCase plugin installation... with no solution in sight. Good Luck!

Comment: @thedp I was able to install the CCRC plugin in 64-bit Juno using the above solution, although some functionality seems to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use a Clearcase plugin with Eclipse Juno or later (Kepler), the [Open Source ClearCase plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/) (not from IBM) works.

If you are a 64 bits user, it seems that Erez A. Korn's workaround does not work, so you have to fallback on another plugin.

Comment: +1 good to know, and I see that plugin has some recent evolutions in it.

Comment: The answer selected doesn't work with Juno 64 bit, this one works! Thanks!

Comment: @Newbie : Thanks for you input. I won't change the selected answer but will add a not to my answer.

Comment: Great suggestion, I even prefer it to the one from IBM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a "Eclipse4.0 support" issue, as the [official Eclipse versions supported for the IBM plugin are all 3.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256383).

Note that this isn't the only plugin suffering from this installation error message: the [TeamCity plugin also get the same kind of error](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/434882). (see [TW-20759](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20759)).

Comment: Thank you, the first link in my message mentioned the plugin installation "For Eclipse versions 3.4.x and later", but I guess it really means up to 3.X.

Comment: @XavierT. knowing IBM for a few years now, especially regarding ClearCase, I think this (ie, "3.x only, not yet 4.x") is a safe assumption ;)

Comment: see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586 for an updated CCRC compatibility table.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod CCRC isn't the same than ClearCase though.

Answer (score 0):

ClearTeam Explorer which comes with version 8 of clearCase should have no problem with Juno

Answer (score 0):

The org.eclipse.update.core JAR can be copied over to the eclipse instance's plugins directory from the IMShared\plugins directory to resolve the issue.

Comment: In fact I copied below 3 jars and it worked with even Neon version
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.1.0.jar ,
org.eclipse.update.core_3.1.1.jar ,
org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.2.200.v20120521-2346.jar