# Trouble installing Rational Team Concert Eclipse client

Tags: eclipse, rtc, rational-team-concert

I'm having trouble installing the Rational Team Concert 4.0 Eclipse client onto my existing Eclipse installation.

My Eclipse installation is Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Indigo Service Release 2.

When I try to install the RTC client into it, I get the following error:

```
Offering cannot be installed into this existing Eclipse installation configuration because it would invalidate existing bundle constraints
```

Details:

```
Message ID: CRIMA1056E

  CRIMA1054E: Installing bundle "org.eclipse.xsd_2.6.0.v20100914-1218" into this existing Eclipse installation does not meet the version tolerance of "[2.7.0,3.0.0)" for the existing bundle "org.eclipse.xsd.edit"
```

I checked http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/rationalinstall/Install+into+an+existing+Eclipse+instance, but there is not yet a section for Rational Team Concert 4.0.

Are there prerequisites I need to install into Eclipse? Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention in "[Install RTC Eclipse Client 4.0 into an existing Eclipse 3.6.2 using Installation Manager](https://jazz.net/library/article/949/)", you must use the Installation Manager, and a special kind of RTC release:
See "[When will RTC support Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/71887/when-will-rtc-support-eclipse-37-indigo)"

> You can download the p2 Install Repository zip from the [All Downloads tab](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0?p=allDownloads).
>
> Use the Eclipse installer (Help -> Install New Software) to install it into your own Eclipse 3.7 installation

[p2 Install Repository](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0/RTC-Client-p2Repo-4.0.zip)

(Make sure you don't have a similar dependency issue with Juno than in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261634/ibm-clearcase-plugin-installation-issue-with-eclipse-juno), which wasn't about RTC, but could also be relevant).

Other requirements are described in "[CLMSystemRequirements](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/CLMSystemRequirements)"
(you need a jazz.net login, but you request and create one easily)
(System Requirements for CLM 2012 including Jazz Foundation, Rational Team Concert, Rational Quality Manager and Rational Requirements Composer )
See the ["Eclipse IDE" section](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/CLMSystemRequirements#Eclipse): Eclipse 3.7.2 is supported with RTC4.0 (part of CLM2012).

Comment: Thanks VonC!
I wish I had known about that article about installing RTC Eclipse Client 4.0. I installed those prerequisites and it works!